# pythonic way of calling specific keys/values from a nest dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

What's a pythonic way of getting specific keys/values from a nested dictionary?

For instance, I want to get all the dict values that are odd from this nested dictionary:

```
nested_dict = {'bulldog': {'type': 3}, 'cat': {'type': 4}, 'yorkie': {'type': 11}, 'pitbull': {'type': 8}}
```

The output should look something like this:

```
new_dict = {'bulldog': {'type': 3}, 'yorkie': {'type': 11}}
```

Additionally, what if I wanted pull only the nested keys with an odd value, in which case the output would look like this:

```
new_dict2 = {'type': 3, 'type': 11}
```

Comment: `new_dict2` has duplicate keys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fairly straight forward using a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) like:

#### Code:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in nested_dict.items() if v['type'] % 2 != 0}
```

#### Test Code:

```
nested_dict = {'bulldog': {'type': 3}, 'cat': {'type': 4},
               'yorkie': {'type': 11}, 'pitbull': {'type': 8}}

new_dict = {k: v for k, v in nested_dict.items() if v['type'] % 2 != 0}
print(new_dict)
```

#### Results:

```
{'bulldog': {'type': 3}, 'yorkie': {'type': 11}}
```

Comment: thank you for this, exactly what I was looking for! I was trying to use a dict comprehension but couldn't get it to work properly with a nested dictionary. this is super helpful.